# Easier way to set command line arguments for debug?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, command-line-arguments

I know that in VS you set command line arguments in the properties editor -> Debug -> Command line arguments.

But I find it very cumbersome when debugging various args!

Is there some kind of shortcut or "specify as you go" method of setting the args?

I.e. a popup dialog when you hit F5 to start debugging? With same as last time as default? And possibly a dropdown with recently used args?

Comment: I realize that you can leave the property editor window open for easier access. Perhaps that's good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way for that, but the extension [SmartCommandlineArguments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MBulli.SmartCommandlineArguments) was helpful for me.

You find the window in *View/Other windows/Commandline arguments*.

[image: Screenshot of the extension]